# How to access the body of a request outside in an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous, request

So I have a post route which is an async await function, and I have a reuest inside it which pulls some data from the api and I want to save the content of that body in a variable outside the request function

I have tried using promises but I am not really familiar with that.

```
//@route POST api/portfolio/stock
//@desc Create or update a user's stock portfolio
//@access private
router.post(
  "/stock",
  auth,
  [
    check("symbol", "symbol is require or incorrect.")
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
    check("qty", "Quantity of the stock purchased is required")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { stock, qty } = req.body;

    const newPortfolio = {};
    newPortfolio.user = req.user.id;
    newPortfolio.stocks = [];
    if(stock) newPortfolio.stocks.stock = stock;
    if(qty) newPortfolio.stocks.qty = qty;

    request(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=${stock}&apikey=${config.get(
            "API_KEY")}`, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) console.error(error);

            if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                        res.status(404).json({msg: 'No stock found'});
                      }

            let content = JSON.parse(body);
            let quote = content['Global Quote'];
        });

    newPortfolio.stocks.stockInfo = quote;

    try {

        let portfolio = await Portfolio.findOne({ user: user.req.id });

        //update if exists
        if(portfolio) {

            portfolio = await Portfolio.findOneAndUpdate(
                { user: user.req.id },
                { $push: { stocks: newPortfolio.stocks }}
            );

            return res.json(portfolio);

        }

        //create if not found
        portfolio = new Portfolio(newPortfolio);
        await portfolio.save();
        res.json(portfolio);

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  }
);
```

I want to save myPortfolio.stocks.stockInfo using body of that request.

Comment: You don't.  You continue the rest of your function INSIDE the `request()` callback because that's the ONLY place the `body` data is available.  This is the basics of asynchronous programming in Javascript.  You can also use promises and `async/await`, but that requires you learn how to properly use promises and `async/await` so you can use it properly.  Hint, the `request-promise` library is a promise-returning version of the `request` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to access the body of a request outside in an async function?

You don't.  Asynchronous results are only available in the asynchronous context.  For an asynchronous function that returns the result via a callback, that means you consume/use the results INSIDE the callback.  Any code that needs access to those results goes in the callback.  In traditional async Javascript programming, you just continue the code of your function inside the callback.

Fortunately, promises and the invention of `async` and `await` can make the coding a bit simpler.  For asynchronous functions that return a promise (instead of taking a callback), you can use `await` to get their result and you can write code that looks more like the sequential model, even though it's still asynchronous.

For example, this is what a rewrite of your function might look like where we switch the request-promise library (same as the request library, but returns a promise instead of uses a callback) and then we use `await` on the result:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

router.post(
    "/stock",
    auth,
    [
        check("symbol", "symbol is require or incorrect.")
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
        check("qty", "Quantity of the stock purchased is required")
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                errors: errors.array()
            });
        }

        const {
            stock,
            qty
        } = req.body;

        const newPortfolio = {};
        newPortfolio.user = req.user.id;
        newPortfolio.stocks = [];
        if (stock) newPortfolio.stocks.stock = stock;
        if (qty) newPortfolio.stocks.qty = qty;

        try {
            let body = await rp(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=${stock}&apikey=${config.get("API_KEY")}`);
            let content = JSON.parse(body);
            newPortfolio.stocks.stockInfo = content['Global Quote'];
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            res.status(404).json({
                msg: 'No stock found'
            });
            return;
        }


        try {

            let portfolio = await Portfolio.findOne({
                user: user.req.id
            });

            //update if exists
            if (portfolio) {

                portfolio = await Portfolio.findOneAndUpdate({
                    user: user.req.id
                }, {
                    $push: {
                        stocks: newPortfolio.stocks
                    }
                });

                return res.json(portfolio);

            }

            //create if not found
            portfolio = new Portfolio(newPortfolio);
            await portfolio.save();
            res.json(portfolio);

        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send("Server Error");
        }
    }
);
```

Note: your adding properties to `newPortfolio.stocks` which is an array is quite unusual. While it's not technically wrong, you would usually declare `newPortfolio.stocks`  to be an object, not an array if you were just going to add properties to it and not use it like an actual array.  It can often be confusing to people reading your code if you use the same variable as both an object and an array.  Usually, you want a variable (or property) to behave as one or the other, not both.

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot, with your help I was able to pull store data to newPortfolio.stocks and I changed it to an object, but when i post this request in postman is says server error and says user is not defined, do you have a fix for that?

Comment: @SakshamSaraswat - I do not understand what your new problem is.  Perhaps you should describe exactly what the issue is in a new question?